# Alternate way of "As" keyword in laravel 8 routing

Tags: laravel

This is the routing is workable in Laravel 5.8.*

Route::get('/dashboardone',['as'=>'dashboard-one', 'uses'=>'DashboardController@index'] );

How i can use **('as'=>'dashboard-one')** in Laravel 8.x? below is laravel 8.x route

Route::get('/dashboardone',[App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'index']);

what i should define in routing and how to call this by nickName.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named routes can be done like this ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes)):

```
Route::get('/dashboardone', [\App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard-one');
```